# jQuery maskmoney, no value returned to controller on form submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using jquery-maskmoney (https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney) for a currency input field. When I don't use the mask, the value entered is passed to the controller, when I use the mask, I get the value 0.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-width-xlarge"} })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The following to hook up the field:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#Amount').maskMoney();
    })
</script>
```

Problem is, when the mask is used, the value 0 is returned to the controller, when I do not use the mask I get the value entered.

Rendered HTML for the field is

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Amount must be a number." data-val-range="The field Amount must be between 0 and 10000000000." data-val-range-max="10000000000" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-required="The Amount field is required." htmlattributes="{ class = form-control input-width-xlarge }" id="Amount" name="Amount" type="text" value="0">
```

The Controller method is:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ReceiptId,DonorId,Amount,CreationDate,CurrencyId,PaymentTypeId,AllocationId,LegacyAllocation,Activity,Diocese,Acknowledgement,Printed,OwnerId,LastUserId,LastUpdated,GiftAid,Notes")] CreateReceiptViewModel crvm)
```

I've tried using EditorFor instead of TextBoxFor, same result.

Comment: Please do not put "SOLVED" into your OP or title.  Simply "accept" the best answer below.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED: Problem was Amount in the View Model was a Decimal but a String was being returned, so it was failing the validation. Which makes sense now I think about it :)

Solution was to introduce a new String field called DisplayAmount in the view model and use that in the view. Changed the binding so that it looked for DisplayAmount, and in the action parsed that into the Amount.

Model looks like this:

```
    [Required]
    [Range(0.0,10000000000)]
    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please supply the amount.")]
    public String DisplayAmount { get; set; }
```

View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DisplayAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-width-xlarge"} })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the Action:

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ReceiptId,DonorId,DisplayAmount,CreationDate,CurrencyId,PaymentTypeId,AllocationId,LegacyAllocation,Activity,Diocese,Acknowledgement,Printed,OwnerId,LastUserId,LastUpdated,GiftAid,Notes")] CreateReceiptViewModel crvm) {
        Decimal amount;
        Decimal.TryParse(crvm.DisplayAmount, out amount);

        crvm.Amount = amount;
```